# What type should a get function for a member held by value have?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

```
class A { /* */ };

class B {
private:
    A mA;
};
```

Assume that we do not want to return `B::mA` by value here - we want to manipulate exactly the instance inside `B`, call functions on it, etc. What type should we use for `B::getA()`? Our options are:

1. `A*`. Can be deleted on caller side or stored past object lifetime.
2. `A&`. Can cause copy creation if caller uses `A a = b->getA()` instead of `A& a = b->getA()`.
3. `A&` plus `explicit A::A(A&)`. Suppresses the unintended copy creation but now `A` depends on `B`'s implementation details. The issue of having the ref stored past object lifetime stands.
4. Weak pointer. Same storage problem plus lots of confusion - weak pointers are just not for that.
5. Some artificial templated pointer type meant only as a message not to delete or store it. Working but clumsy.

Did I miss anything?

Comment: 1-3 make it kind of useless to declare B as private in the first place. Once you return a non-const reference you can make the member public as well.

Comment: Regarding 1., raw owning pointers are to be prohibited anyway, so returning `A*` already means "don't `delete` me".

Comment: Can you do an example? I can only agree with tobi303. If you don't want to encapsulate something then don't. Depending on the context, you might think about setting something as a friend instead.

Comment: @tobi303 Not really. Say, I want to log access to this member.

Comment: When I first read about "why getters are evil" (dont find the link atm) I was a bit shocked, but after a while it made sense. Any how, if you dont want to make a copy, then writing a getter method is most likely not what you should do.

Comment: @sigil If it is about logging access, consider this: As soon as some other source has a direct reference, it is able to give it away. So the responsibility of logging can't be secured.

Comment: @tobi303 That article is more about naming... so not really addressing the problem here. Nevertheless I agree that using more meaningful verbs for functions is definitely better. Thanks for the link though.

Comment: @Quentin "Regarding 1., raw owning pointers are to be prohibited anyway, so returning A* already means "don't delete me"." Could you please provide a link for this? Such a change would break an unimaginable amount of code.

Comment: I would change the design to eliminate the need for an accessor. Tell, don't ask.

Comment: @sigil: it's not an enforced change, but it's a modern guideline that should be *almost* **always** followed. Use smart pointers for ownership, never raw pointers.

Comment: @SimonKraemer oh sorry. To be honest I didnt read it before posting it here ;). I was more thinking in the line of: "provide the interface the clients needs to make the class do its job instead of providing getters so that clients can access the internals to do the job". I am sure there are articles out there about that, just dont find it anymore

Comment: There is even a rule: https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rh-get

Comment: @Rob K "I would change the design to eliminate the need for an accessor. Tell, don't ask." The only way I can imagine for this would be to wrap up all `A`'s public functions in `B`. Which, in my case, amounts to maybe 100 function declarations from 7 layers of inheritance. No can do.

Comment: How about wrapping your member in a std::shared_ptr and return a std::weak_ptr version of that? Shouldn't this solve most of your problems?

Comment: @Simon Kraemer "How about wrapping your member in a std::shared_ptr and return a std::weak_ptr version of that? Shouldn't this solve most of your problems?" It certainly would. However, I'd prefer to avoid holding `B::mA` by pointer here - it adds the costs of allocation/deallocation for basically no reason.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend returning `A&` - the user of the method can indeed misuse it, but that's true for pretty much everything in C++, and returning a reference to something is idiomatic.

Nevertheless, if you want to make it harder *(but still not impossible)* for the client to misuse your getter, consider returning an [`std::reference_wrapper<A>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper), which makes it more difficult to make accidental copies (*):

```
std::reference_wrapper<A> a = some_b.get_a();
auto b = a; // doesn't copy `A` - it copies its address
A c = a; // copies, because `a` is implicitly convertible to `A&`
```

This approach has the drawback that `std::reference_wrapper::get()` must be used to access `A`'s members *(as we still do not have an overloadable `operator.`)*.

---

**(*)**: making an accidental copy is the least of your issues. The user could retain the reference to `some_b.mA` even after `some_b` dies, creating a *dangling reference*! This sort of mistake is what Rust catches at compile-time thanks to its *borrow checker*.

If have a very good reason to make the above situation very hard *(but still not impossible!)*, you could use an higher-order function instead of a getter:

```
class A { /* */ };

class B {
private:
    A mA;

public:
    template <typename TF>
    void mutate_a(TF&& f) 
    { 
        // <`static_assert` that `f` takes `A&` here>
        f(mA); 
    }
};
```

Usage:

```
B some_b;
some_b.mutate_a([](A& a)
{
    // <do something with `a` here>
});
```

As you can see it is harder to take `a` outside of the lambda, but the syntactical overhead is only worth it in very particular situations. My recommendation of returning `A&` and "trusting the user" still stands.

Comment: why bother to write a getter that returns a reference when you get (almost) he same effect with a public member (with much less writing)? Not trolling, but really interested to know why ;)

Comment: @tobi303: no real reason - my answer starts from assumption that OP is going to write a getter. The title of the question is in fact: *"What type should a get function for a member held by value have?"*, so I automatically excluded the possibility of not using a getter as it is out of the scope of the question.

Comment: I think the crucial point is that OP wants to avoid the copy. I am just missing a mentioning of `const` when the question may seem like asking for getter in the general case. Nevermind, maybe I am just too pedantic.

Comment: @tobi303 One advantage I could think of would be hiding the implementation details from the developer/user of the class. Let's say you decide to move `mA` into a struct and use the struct as a member of `B` - Using a getter you will only have to change the function itself. Or when using interfaces...

Comment: @SimonKraemer nice example, I am convinced ;)

Comment: @Vittorio Romeo I'm experimenting with `std::reference_wrapper` here and it does not appear to prohibit copying. This example prints `0`, which means that `av` is a copy: http://ideone.com/7kWWt5

Comment: @sigil yes, if you explicitly say `A a = ...` it won't, but if you say `auto a = ...` it will. In the first case the user is explicitly trying to make a copy, the second one could be an accident. Reference wrapper is implicitly convertible to `A&`. Consider making your own wrapper that isn't to avoid the behaviour you posted.

Comment: @tobi303: The advantages are rather obvious: implementation hiding.  A reference-returning getter does not explose the fact that the returned  lvalue is a member of the object that provides the getter. With public field that fact is immediately exposed. With public field you immediately see that the lifetime of the field is tied to the lifetime of the owning object. With the getter don't see anything like that.